# choosing a variable name based on option elements value

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am making a quiz website where user can select the category from the option element, i store the value in my questionCategory variable and console log it to see it get it, and it does. I have arrays of objects with same variable names as values in my options element. when i pass it as a parameter in my function to start the quiz it does not load the array, while console log outputs the proper value and when hardcoded it works with no issues.

```
function startQuiz(numOfQuestions){
  questionCount = document.getElementById("selectQuestionCount").selectedIndex;
  questionPoll = document.getElementsByClassName("questionCount")[questionCount].value;

  categoryType = document.getElementById("selectCategoryType").selectedIndex;
  questionCategory = document.getElementsByClassName("categoryType")[categoryType].value;

  console.log(questionCategory);
  console.log(questionPoll);

  $("#questions_div").show();
  score=0;
  currentQuestion = 0;
  totalQuestions = questionPoll;

  loadQuestions(currentQuestion,questionCategory);
}

function loadQuestions(i,j){
  mainQuestion.text(j[i].question);
  opt1.text(j[i].ans1);
  opt2.text(j[i].ans2);
  opt3.text(j[i].ans3);
  opt4.text(j[i].ans4);
}
```

expecting to change the questionCategory based on the value of the option box and call in the loadQuestion function.

Comment: `questionCategory` is being set from a `value`, which is a String.  `String`s do not have a `question` property on them in javascript.

Comment: question is a property from the array of objects, but i will see if i can return the value and then pass it at a parameter in the     loadQuestions function

Comment: I'm just pointing out with the logic you currently have, what you are passing to the method, and what the method is trying to use off of it.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, i used a function to take the categoryName as a parameter and return the name of the object when the value matches :) its all working now

Answer (score 0):

```
function getCategoryName(ctgName){
    if(questionCategory == "historyQuestions"){
      return historyQuestions;
    } else if(questionCategory == "randomQuestions")
      return randomQuestions;
  }
```

The goal of this piece of code is to get a value out of the html option element and use it as a object name to access the array inside that object.

```
    questionCategory = document.getElementsByClassName("categoryType")
[categoryType].value;
```

was giving me back a string and i could not use the `question` property on it.
the function `getCategoryName` would accept a parameter - `questionCategory` which stores the string and does a comparison with the "string".

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, you may consider doing something like:

```js
// external.js
$(function(){ // load
var array1 = ['a', 'b', 1], array2 = ['c', 'd', 2], array3 = ['e', 'f', 3], array4 = ['g', 'h', 4];
var array5 = ['i', 'j', 5], array6 = ['k', 'l', 6], array7 = ['m', 'n', 7];
var arrayOfArrays = [array1, array2, array3, array4, array5, array6, array7];
var content = $('#content'), sel = $('#sel'), out = $('#outcome');
sel.change(function(){
  // .text instead of .html so it is escaped
  out.text(JSON.stringify(arrayOfArrays[$(this).prop('selectedIndex')]));
});
content.css('display', 'block'); // in case you're generating some gui with JavaScript
}); // load end
```

```css
/* external.css */
*{
  padding:0; margin:0; box-sizing:border-box; overflow:hidden;
}
html,body{
  width:100%; height:100%; background:#aaa; color:#000;
}
body{
  position:relative; font:22px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
body>*{
  position:absolute;
}
#content{
  display:none; width:100%; height:100%; 
}
.page{
  position:relative; width:100%; height:100%; float:left;
}
.bar{
   width:100%; height:38px; padding:3px; background:#ccc; color:#000;
}
.main{
  height:calc(100% - 38px); padding:5px; overflow-y:auto;
}
h1{
  font-size:28px; margin-left:3px;
}
#sel{
  font:22px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; margin-left:4px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1, user-scalable=no' />
    <title>Select Example</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='external.css' />
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div id='content'>
    <div class='page'>
      <div class='bar'><h1>Select Example</h1></div>
      <div class='main'>
        <label for='sel'>Please select a value:</label><select id='sel'>
          <option value='1'>value 1</option>
          <option value='2'>value 2</option>
          <option value='3'>value 3</option>
          <option value='4'>value 4</option>
          <option value='5'>value 5</option>
          <option value='6'>value 6</option>
          <option value='7'>value 7</option>
        </select>
        <div id='outcome'></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```